# How can I implement this UI?

Tags: android, tablet

I am developing app for tablet devices only. It is like a master-detail window. Left side of window shows the menu and right side of window show the questions to get information of person. it has test box, checkbox etc.
There are four menu options:

1) Personal Info

2)Job Info

3)Contact details

4)Finish

If the user selects any one of the options in left side, the right side window shows related question. And then the user is allowed to fill the options in that window. After filling the options from 1 to 3, when the user chooses 4)finish button, then the information entered should be summarised.

If user provides any wrong information or need to edit the information, user will choose particular menu , edit it and then click finish button for summary.

There is no order for selecting the menu, user can select any menu randomly to fill the information.

How can I implement this?

Comment: show some code that you have tried

Comment: Use Fragments one for your menu option and other fragments as per you menu selection.

Comment: I know only basics in android app development. I don't write any code for this. I want to know the way to write this app. Can please give some example for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Fragments :

What are fragments?

A fragment is an independent Android component which can be used by an activity. A fragment encapsulates functionality so that it is easier to reuse within activities and layouts.

A fragment runs in the context of an activity, but has its own life cycle and typically its own user interface. It is also possible to define fragments without an user interface, i.e., headless fragments.

**2. Fragments**

**2.1. What are single-pane or multi-pane layouts?**

Android devices exists in a variaty of screen sizes and densities.

A panel or pane represents a part of the user interface. The term pane is a general term used to describe the concept that multiple views are combined into one compound view depending on the actual available space.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Thanks Anil Meenugu. how the data collected from different page retain to last page? Also I have read some thread. one Activity for multiple fragments or multiple activity for multiple fragments. For my need , can you please suggest which one is suitable?